# How to use predictions recursively to forecast time series data

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, time-series

Lately I've been working with time series data. Been researching a lot, but haven't found someone that takes care of this (very basic) issue.

Say, I have data from period `t=8` to `t=50`. I'm using lag 1,2 and 7, because this is daily data, and I need to make 7-day forecasts. So, I train my model with data from `t=8` to `t=43`, to predict from `t=44` to `t=50`.

So, my train data looks like this:

```
 t    Q     Q_lag1     Q_lag2     Q_lag7
 8    10      11          12         9
 9    14      10          11         8
 .     .       .           .         . 
 .     .       .           .         . 
 .     .       .           .         . 
 43    25      24         22         20
```

No problem here. I can train my model, Q is `y_train` and the rest of the columns are `X_train`. But then, if I want to test my model for forecasting if I do something like this:

```
forecast= clf.predict(X_test)
```

I will be using data that, in practice I will not know.

Say, for predicting the value for Q in `t=48`, I need data from lag 1, lag 2, and lag 7, which is `t=47` , `t=46` and `t=40`, but in practice I will only have data until `t=43` which means I need to use the predictions from `t=47`and `t=46` , instead of the actual values.

This should be fairly standard, but couldn't find people addressing it. Do you know how can I recursively replace my X_test data with the predictions?

Comment: You should write a loop starting from the day you need to predict first. This is called recurrent prediction for time series, if I'm not mistaken.